# X-Forwarding: Characters are not displayed properly

Tags: ssh, xforwarding, x

I am connecting to via SSH and activated x-forwarding

```
[user@client]# ssh -X root@h2795107.stratoserver.net
```

And open a graphical program (like gedit)

```
[user@server]# gedit
```

It opens, however, **characters are not displayed properly**:

[image]

Client (my machine): Ubuntu 18 / Remote Server: Centos 7

Comment: Different fonts, different font encodings, Gnome getting confused between local and remote fonts? Does `xfontsel` work and display fonts properly?

Comment: @dirkt Thanks a lot. It was a font issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out that there was a font missing on the server. I installed *dejavu-lgc-sans-fonts* on the remote server.

```
yum install dejavu-lgc-sans-fonts
```

After this everything worked fine.